# find a fixed date format using regex python3?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

> find a fixed date format using regex python3?

```
import re 
input_file= "xxx","06/05/2018","07/05/2018","09/05/20"

dob_list = []

def check_dob(input_string):
    return re.findall(r"[\d]{1,2}/[\d]{1,2}/[\d]{2}", input_string)


def read_file(input_text):
for x in input_text:
    var_dob = check_dob(x)
    if len(var_dob) > 0:
        dob_list.append(var_dob)
        print(var_dob)

 read_file(input_file)
```

> Expected Output:

```
  09/05/20
```

> Got Output:

```
  06/05/2018
  07/05/2018
  09/05/20
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost correct, use

```
[\d]{1,2}\/[\d]{1,2}\/[\d]{2}\b
```

instead (add `\b` at the end of your regex).

`\b` signifies the word boundary. Putting it at the end prevent any character to be matched afterwards.

You could also put it at both the front and the end of your regex. For example:

```
\b[\d]{1,2}/[\d]{1,2}/[\d]{2}\b
```

This will make sure it does not match strings with extraneous characters at the front and back (such as `"09/02/2018"`, `"1109/02/20"`, etc)